# Google Calendar API to get the working hours data from google calendar settings

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Can we get the Working hours data from google calendar settings. I have gone through the APIs of calendar

: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/settings/get

but didn't get the required data with this. Attaching the image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, in its current form, this isn't possible through the Calendar API.*

#### Feature Request:

I did a search on Google's Issue Tracker and there is a Feature Request requesting the exposure of Working Hours through the Calendar API already.

You can find this Feature Request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/112248486), which you can give a star (☆) in the top left to let Google know more people wish for this request to be implemented.

Comment: To save you a click that feature request was closed as "Won't Fix" on June 24, 2021.

"mi...@google.com<mi...@google.com> #152 Jun 24, 2021 01:17AM
Status: Won't Fix (Obsolete)
Hello,

Implementing this feature is currently not a priority. Therefore, I'll proceed to close this.

Kind regards."

As of today this duplicate request is still open though:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181655431

Comment: Another feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198667127

Comment: Those requests were closed so I opened a new one: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231620767.

Answer (score 0):

Location access became available in August 2023

- Bulletin: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/08/calendar-api-working-location-read-write-generally-available.html
- API details: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/calendar-status

Note that the UI allows you set every day preferences:

1. top level Settings option
2. or you can set granular level, in the same manner you can set up any event (one-off or repeating)

I have found that if you set times in method (1) you cannot get hold of these via the API so it is better to use method (2)